# How to access the variable of a parameter when creating an object inside a method?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runtime-error

```
 public class responseListener implements  Response.Listener<JSONObject>{
        public String status;
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                status = response.getString("status");
                Log.d("Inside onResponse() ", status);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getImageStatus(String url){
        responseListener response_listener = new responseListener();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, response_listener, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });



        String status=response_listener.status;
        Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this).add(jsonRequest);
        Log.d("In getImageStatus():", status);
        return status;

    }
```

Logcat screen:

```
06-17 10:07:57.231 15799-15849/com.example.user.streetviewman E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                            Process: com.example.user.streetviewman, PID: 15799
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                                at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:143)
                                                                                at com.example.user.streetviewman.MainActivity$LongOperation.getImageStatus(MainActivity.java:194)
                                                                                at com.example.user.streetviewman.MainActivity$LongOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:85)
                                                                                at com.example.user.streetviewman.MainActivity$LongOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:62)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 06-17 10:07:57.396 15799-15799/com.example.user.streetviewman D/yo myannn inside:: ZERO_RESULTS
```

Log.d("Inside onResponse()", status) returns **ZERO_RESULTS** at the last line of logcat, which is the response I want but Log.d("In getImageStatus", status) returns null and I get the error: " java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message".**What can I do to get Log.d("In getImageStatus",status) to return ZERO_RESULTS instead of null ?**

All these methods are inside a class **LongOperation** which extends **AsyncTask**. I am calling **getImageStatus()** from **doInBackground()** method of LongOperation.

Comment: Yet another... Response is ready in onResponse not early(not at the time of return from getImageStatus)

Comment: +Selvin please can you help? What should I do next  ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two Strings named "status".  Change the name of the 2nd one, it probably doesn't know which to use

Comment: Thanks but I do not think that is the problem. I tried your suggestion, it did not work.

Comment: you made the first "status" string public, so try String s = status;  in place of    String status = response_listener.status;   then change   "status" to "s" in the Log.d statement

Answer (score 0):

In `responseListener` class, `status` variable is only assigned a value when `onResponse` is called. So it is natural that it returns a `null` value on `String status=response_listener.status`.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a way in which the value of status is not null ?

Comment: I suggest you looking at some Volley examples and how they are handled.